# Map points from one plane into another

Tags: graph-algorithms

Given a point on a plane A, I want to be able to map to a corresponding point on plane B. I have a set of N corresponding pairs of reference points between the two planes, however, the overall mapping is not a simple affine transform (no homographies for me).

Things I have tried:

1. For a given point, find the three closest reference points in plane
   A, compute barrycentric coordinates of that triangle, and then apply
   that transform to the corresponding reference points in plane B. How
   it failed: sometimes the three closest points were nearly collinear,
   so errors were huge. Also, there was no consistency in the mapping
   when crossing borders. It was very "jittery."
2. Compute all possible triangles given the N reference points (N^3).
       Order them by size. For the given point, find the smallest triangle
       that it's in. This fixes the linearly of the points problem, but was
       still extremely jittery and slow.
3. Start with a triangulated plane A. Iterate through the reference
       points, adding each one to the reference plane. Every time you add a
       point it exists in at least one triangle. Break that triangle into
       three triangles using the new reference point as a vertex. You end
       up with plane A triangulated so you can map from plane A to plane B
       with ease. Issues: You can prove that every triangle will have a
       point that is on the edge of the planes. This results in huge errors
       if your reference points are far from the edge of the planes.

I feel like this should be a fairly standard problem. Are there standard algorithms/libraries for this?

Comment: What objective function are you trying to optimize?  What are your constraints?  (Do you want a homeomorphism, an immersion, a submersion, or something else?  Does the map have to be piecewise linear?)  Why do you care if the map is "jittery"?  And what is an "edge" of a plane?  (Planes are infinite.)  What, in this context, is an "error"?

Comment: Try Delaunay triangulation

Comment: Dude I love you. That's what I was looking for. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: This is a long-dead post, but how does one actually implement this transformation? I love Delaunay triangles… but is there a good pointer to best practices in this type of mapping?